# python version of C unsigned char

Tags: python, char

I need help with a python version for this C code:

```
#define HostBusy_high   0x02
#define control_register    0x37a

Out32 (control_register,(unsigned char)(Inp32(control_register) | HostBusy_high));
```

the Out32 and Inp32 are functions located in the inpout32.dll used to interface parallel ports. These functions take hex values as their parameters. I tried to code in python to get the desired value but that is not what I am getting. See python version below:

```
from ctypes import windll

#parallel port instance
p_port = windll.inpout32
HostBusy_high = 0x02
control_register = 0x37a

write_data = write(p_port(Inp32(control_register) | HostBusy_high))
 Out32 (control_register,write_data))
```

With the code above i do not seem to get the value I want. I suspect it is the unsigned value.

Thanks

Comment: Needs more context. What are you trying to do with a byte value?

Comment: user680730, no offense, but considering your history @stackoverflow, I'd recommend you to go through the Python tutorial first, and ask question only if something still remains unclear. Here you go: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you just should get the modulo 256 of your value. Then it is surely unsigned. Examples:

```
>>> 12 % 256
12
>>> 1022 % 256
254
>>> -1 % 256
255
>>> -127 % 256
129
```

Comment: In this case, maybe he should just assign a variable a value from 0..255 range? :)

Comment: I am not sure what he wants. Maybe he gets values between -128 and 127 and need the two's complement when it is negative. Not sure though.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on why you need an unsigned char. For most purposes you'll just use a Python integer. If you need to actually have a one-byte datum, you can use Python's struct.pack to make a one-byte byte string out of an integer.

You can't, in general, get good results by doing line by line literal translation of code between languages, without a good understanding of both the source and target languages, as well as the body of code you're translating.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a match in the ctypes library with the `c_ubyte` data type. See if you populate an object of that type with your value and find if its suitable.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_ubyte

The rest of the types are tabulated in
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types